# Make Clean Run Error [2]

Tags: makefile, build

Getting some environment setup error I'm not familiar with it, anyone whats going on?

```
    Admins-MacBook-Pro:foo.com kiararobles$ make clean
    rm -rf /Volumes/Bulk
    (slow)/Users/kiararobles/documents/foo.com/.bundle/Volumes/Bulk 
    (slow)/Users/kiararobles/documents/foo.com/.sass-cache/Volumes/Bulk    
    (slow)/Users/kiararobles/documents/foo.com/public
    /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
    /bin/sh: -c: line 0: `rm -rf /Volumes/Bulk
    (slow)/Users/kiararobles/documents/foo.com/.bundle /Volumes/Bulk              
    (slow)/Users/kiararobles/documents/foo.com/.sass-cache /Volumes/Bulk 
    (slow)/Users/kiararobles/documents/foo.com/public'
    make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

Comment: Do you maybe mean `$(slow)`? That's how `make` handles variables that you set in the makefile.

Comment: We can't help you unless you show the makefile recipe.